# How to call std::unique with custom predicate in C++03?

Tags: c++, lambda, functor, c++03

I saw this example of how to do it in C++11:

```cpp
std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), [](float l, float r)
{ 
  return std::abs(l - r) < 0.01; 
});
```

However, this fails for me in C++03:

```
error: template argument for 'template<class _FIter, class _BinaryPredicate> _FIter std::unique(_FIter, _FIter, _BinaryPredicate)' uses local type 'CRayTracer::myFunc()::<lambda(float, float)>'
```

How can I do this in C++03? I think Lambdas may have already existed, and functors/function objects existed, right? Just looking for a simple solution, does not need to be extendable - it will only ever be used here.

Here is an example of code which will not compile for me:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main(){
    std::vector<float> v;
    v.push_back(1.0);
    v.push_back(1.0);
    v.push_back(3.5);
    v.push_back(3.5);

    struct approx_equal
    {
        bool operator()(float l, float r)
        {
            return std::abs(l - r) < 0.01;
        }
    };
    approx_equal f;

    std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(),f);
}
```

Here's the error it produced:

```
testUnique.cpp: In function 'int main()':
testUnique.cpp:21:37: error: no matching function for call to 'unique(std::vector<float>::iterator, std::vector<float>::iterator, main()::approx_equal&)'
   21 |     std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(),f);
      |                                     ^
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/algorithm:62,
                 from testUnique.cpp:3:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:995:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _FIter> _FIter std::unique(_FIter, _FIter)'
  995 |     unique(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last)
      |     ^~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:995:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testUnique.cpp:21:37: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 3 provided
   21 |     std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(),f);
      |                                     ^
In file included from C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/algorithm:62,
                 from testUnique.cpp:3:
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1025:5: note: candidate: 'template<class _FIter, class _BinaryPredicate> _FIter std::unique(_FIter, _FIter, _BinaryPredicate)'
 1025 |     unique(_ForwardIterator __first, _ForwardIterator __last,
      |     ^~~~~~
C:/msys64/mingw64/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1025:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
testUnique.cpp: In substitution of 'template<class _FIter, class _BinaryPredicate> _FIter std::unique(_FIter, _FIter, _BinaryPredicate) [with _FIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<float*, std::vector<float> >; _BinaryPredicate = main()::approx_equal]':
testUnique.cpp:21:37:   required from here
testUnique.cpp:21:37: error: template argument for 'template<class _FIter, class _BinaryPredicate> _FIter std::unique(_FIter, _FIter, _BinaryPredicate)' uses local type 'main()::approx_equal'
   21 |     std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(),f);
      |                                     ^
testUnique.cpp:21:37: error:   trying to instantiate 'template<class _FIter, class _BinaryPredicate> _FIter std::unique(_FIter, _FIter, _BinaryPredicate)'
```

And here was my set of flags:

```
g++ -c -g -O3 -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -m64 -Wshadow -Wall -DMX_COMPAT_32 -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -D__WIN32__ -std=c++03 testUnique.cpp -o testUnique.o
```

Comment: Not lambda function: are introduced in C++11.

Comment: Lambdas are purely syntactic sugar. Anything you can do with a lambda you can also do (more verbosely) with a function object (possibly templated).

Comment: Snarky comment alert: "How can I do this in C++03?" - Why don't you just move your code to C++17? Don't get stuck in the past.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I think Lambdas may have already existed,

No. Lambdas have been introduced in C++11.

> ... and functors/function objects existed, right?

Functors are simply objects with an `operator()`, so they always have been there (though not sure when the term "functor" was actually introduced for them).

For the formal correct way to put it I refer you to other references, sloppy speaking this

```
auto f = [](float l, float r){ 
  return std::abs(l - r) < 0.01; 
};
f(0.1,0.2);
```

Is equivalent to

```
struct unnamed {
    bool operator()(float l, float r) {
        return std::abs(l - r) < 0.01; 
    }
};
unnamed f;
f(0.1,0.2);
```

I.e. you can always replace a lambda with a handwritten functor class. Create an instance of the functor and pass that instead of the lambda.

Complete example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct approx_equal{
    bool operator()(float l, float r) {
        return std::abs(l - r) < 0.01; 
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<float> v{1.0, 1.0, 3.5, 3.5 };

    approx_equal f;

    v.erase(std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(),f),v.end());

    // sorry this is c++11, replace with iterator loop to see output pre-c++11
    for (const auto& x : v) std::cout << x << " ";  
}
```

PS: In C++03 you cannot define the functor class locally and then use it as template parameter (note you do not explicitly pass it as template parameter, but `unique` has to deduce its type from the parameter you pass in).

Comment: When I try to do this, and then use ```std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), f())```, it fails. ```error: no match for call to '(myFunc()::unnamed) ()'```, as well as ```candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided```

Comment: @TylerShellberg why do you pass `f()` ? `f()` is trying to call `operator()` which would return a `bool` but is missing the parameters. The algorithm expects `f`, not `f()`

Comment: @TylerShellberg btw `unnamed` was just to illustrate, that you usually do not know/care about the name of the lambdas type. When you write the functor to replace the lambda, then of course you should give it a meaningful name

Comment: Alright. I'll change that at some point. For now, I changed to ```f``` and now have more issues. ```error: no matching function for call to 'unique(std::vector<float>::iterator, std::vector<float>::iterator, unnamed&)'```, as well as ```error: template argument for 'template<class _FIter, class _BinaryPredicate> _FIter std::unique(_FIter, _FIter, _BinaryPredicate)' uses local type 'unnamed'```. Does that mean I need to define the struct somewhere in global scope?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to provide working example using `std::unique` with a functor (including properly named one) to eliminate confusion.

Comment: @TylerShellberg sorry I also got a bit confused ;) working on a more complete example

Comment: @TylerShellberg if the error still persists I would suggest you to include a [mcve] in the quesiton. Just take care to not deviate too much from the original question, eg dont include the answer in the question, but just provide the missing context

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 Unfortunately it does not work, my setup is nearly identical to this. Maybe it's a compiler flag issue. I'll try making it on its own with the same compiler flags and see if I get the issue. When I do I can add the example to the post.

Comment: @TylerShellberg the error in your question has some `CRayTracer::myFunc()` which suggests that your setup is far from being identical to my example. If you would just add a [mcve] to your question (as already mentioned, a mcve of your original question) I could try to help

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I meant the part of interest was identical. I don't really think the name of the function matters. Regardless, I have edited the OP to include a minimal example of what will not compile, the flags I used, and the error I received.

Comment: @TylerShellberg ok it turned out it was my fault not to check carefully enoug. Seems like adding -std=c++03 is enough to make it break.

Comment: @TylerShellberg really sorry. I vaguely remembered that something had changed for locally defined classes in c++11, but didnt remember what it was till now. My edit should be fine now with c++03. Perhaps remove your edit from the question, imho it was better before, and it was all my fault. And btw dont forget to call `erase` after `unique`. Similar to `remove`, `unique` does not actually remove elements from the vector, but just leaves the end part in some undefined state

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 All good. Yes, it appears it's just because the structure can't be defined in function scope. If I move it out, it works fine. Thanks! Also, didn't realize unique() doesn't actually remove elements, the description from the pages I read suggests otherwise. ```Eliminates all but the first element from every consecutive group of equivalent elements from the range [first, last) and returns a past-the-end iterator for the new logical end of the range.```

Comment: @TylerShellberg common confusion. It removes from the range `[first,last)` in the sense that the iterator you get returned is the new `last`

Answer (score 2):

Lambdas don't exist in C++03, they were introduced in C++11.

Since your lambda example does not need to capture values, you can replace it with a simple standalone function, you don't need a functor, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

bool approx_equal(float l, float r) {
    return std::abs(l - r) < 0.01;
}

int main(){
    std::vector<float> v;
    v.push_back(1.0);
    v.push_back(1.0);
    v.push_back(3.5);
    v.push_back(3.5);

    std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), approx_equal);
}
```

However, you can use a functor, too.  In your attempt to use a functor, you simply defined the functor type inside of `main()` itself, making it a local type, which the compiler complained about.  Define the functor type in global scope instead (you can still use a local variable to instantiate the type), eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct approx_equal {
    bool operator()(float l, float r) {
        return std::abs(l - r) < 0.01;
    }
};

int main(){
    std::vector<float> v;
    v.push_back(1.0);
    v.push_back(1.0);
    v.push_back(3.5);
    v.push_back(3.5);

    approx_equal f;
    std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), f);

    // or:
    // std::unique(v.begin(), v.end(), approx_equal{});
}
```

Comment: Somehow I thought doing it this way would be uglier. It is prettier, though I may keep the functor if only for the sake of making sure the function doesn't get used or removed erroneously by someone else thinking it was general-purpose. Thanks!

Comment: umm I just had a hard time to remember that in c++03 it wasnt allowed to use locally defined classes as template parameters. Once the functor is not locally defined it is of course nicer to use a simple function